# How to bound generic type in java to only accept Integer and double

Tags: java, generics

```
private <T extends Number> T method(T param){...}
```

This will accept AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short.

I want to only accept Double, Integer, Float.

Comment: What does this method do?

Comment: {return param - 5;} and minus is not defined for Number

Comment: That's not going to work. Read up on boxing, unboxing, and the distinction between primitives and objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't bound the generic type like this, because `Integer`, `Double` and `Float` are `final`. Therefore, they can't be extended.

You can *overload* three methods:

```
private Integer method(Integer param){...}

private Double method(Double param){...}

private Float method(Float param){...}
```

Comment: I dont understand why making Integer, Double and Float as final make not useful for generics, any explanation please  ? or any specific resources to get the answer

Comment: Since `Double`, `Integer` and `Float` are `final`, then `T extends Double` doesn't make sense, since `T` cannot exist (due to the `final` modifier of `Double`). :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe there is a way to do it via generics (since those types you wanted are siblings).

I would instead just overload the method to take in those different parameters. It will look the same to each client, and also, the compiler will give you an error if the client tried to call the method with a wrong type.